# HttpWebRequest API call returns bad request but works from postman

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a customer API endpoint (POST) that works fine from postman.

The Postman settings using which I am able to receive response is like this:

```
URL: 
https://somedomain.com/rest/portal/authenticate 

Headers:
"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
"Referrer": "10.xx.xx.xx"   // Real IP address here

Body: (x-www-form-urlencoded)
"username": "TestAdmin"
"password": "testpassword"
```

This setting works fine and I am able to get response in postman.

Now from the same laptop, I tried to make a POST call from .Net core 3.1 method. I have tried with this code:

```
string userName = _config.GetSection("username").Value;
string Password = _config.GetSection("password").Value;
string BaseURL = _config.GetSection("baseURL").Value;  // https://somedomain.com/rest

var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("username", userName);
dict.Add("password", Password);
            
var client = new HttpClient();
var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, BaseURL + $"/portal/authenticate")
          { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict) };
                          
req.Headers.Add("Referer", "10.xx.xx.xx"); // real IP address entered here

var response = client.SendAsync(req).Result;
string responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

With this approach I am getting `Bad request` error with "Inavlid user" message.

What am I doing wrong here? Is the request I have built is not same as Postman ?

Comment: Have you tried to set the ContentType? `content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`

Comment: Tried this but same error.

Comment: Hi @Bluemarble, I have tried your code and it works fine. could you pls share how is your api? From the Bad Request errror , did you add any model validation?

Answer (score 0):

Once you populate the data in dictionary, build a payload out of it which conforms to
**application/x-www-form-urlencoded** content type.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("username", userName);
dict.Add("password", Password);

string payload = BuildPayload(dic);
```

Function `BuildPayload` is defined to form the entire uri from dictionary objects :

```
private string BuildPayload(Dictionary<string, string> dic)
{
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     int i = 0;
     foreach (var item in dic)
     {
     if (i > 0)
        builder.Append("&");
     builder.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", item.Key, item.Value);
     i++;
     }
     return builder.ToString();
 }
```

Then you can get create StringContent instance which will provide you http content based on created payload string. If you need encoding pass it as second param otherwise leave it as null.

```
StringContent request = new StringContent(payload, null, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Then append your custom header with httpclient instance and call the api with the defined request.

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referrer","10.xx.xx.xx");

HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(<Your api url>, request);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string resultStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Following these steps received 500 Internal server error. :-(

Comment: 500 internal server means some error is occuring at api side, data is reaching to api. Please make sure that api is getting data and debug the api.